# Convert IUIAutomationElement to IUIAutomationElement6, to invoke get_CurrentFullDescription method

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, win32gui, microsoft-ui-automation

I need to get fullDescription property of a UI element using [get_CurrentFullDescription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationelement6-get_currentfulldescription) method of [UIAutomation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/) library of c++ windows.

Issue is I have element as `IUIAutomationElement` instead of `IUIAutomationElement6`, `get_CurrentFullDescription` can only be invoked on element with `IUIAutomationElement6` type.

How can I convert `IUIAutomationElement` to `IUIAutomationElement6`?

I am using `HandlePropertyChangedEvent` method to listen on changes in UI, which returns:

```
HRESULT HandlePropertyChangedEvent(
  [in] IUIAutomationElement *sender,
  [in] PROPERTYID           propertyId,
  [in] VARIANT              newValue
);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationpropertychangedeventhandler-handlepropertychangedevent

Here, I need to access FullDescription property of `sender` element coming from `HandlePropertyChangedEvent` function.

Comment: [`QueryInterface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iunknown-queryinterface(refiid_void)).

Comment: @IInspectable thanks, can you give me a slight idea of how to use QueryInterface? like what will be REFIID & ppvObject in this case?   
Thanks in advance, means a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@IInspectable mentioned QueryInterface hint in comments, based on that here is answer:

```
CComPtr<IUIAutomationElement> pElement;
// Code to initialize pElement goes here
CComPtr<IUIAutomationElement6> pElement6;
HRESULT hr = pElement->QueryInterface(&pElement6);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // Use the pElement6 object here
}
```